# Python - Autenticação HTTP Digest com urllib2

Tags: python, xml, web-service, http, autenticação-http

Precisei fazer autenticação em um servidor de testes para 
consumir um serviço em um webservice, consegui fazer a 
autenticação e gerar o xml com o seguinte codigo baseado em um codigo
do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131403/http-basic-authentication-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-urllib2-in-python/5131492#5131492)

```
operacao = 'consulta'
Agencia = "X"
Agente = "X"
Origem = 1
Destino = 2
Data = 2014-06-17

params = '?operacao=%s&agencia=%s&agente=%s&origem=%s&destino=destino&data=%s&idtransacao=c2153663a6a6a8733f58b8c79&fpag=J0' %(operacao, Agencia, Agente, Origem, Destino, Data)

oPass = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
oPass.add_password(None, Url, User, Password)

authHandler = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(oPass)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authHandler)

resposta = opener.open("%s%s" %(Url, params)) #Retorna um XML
print resposta.read() #Leitura do XML
resposta.close()
```

Estive estudando a biblioteca urllib2 para entender as 
classes e metodos: `HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm`, `add_password`, 
`HTTPDigestAuthHandler`, `build_opener`.

Estou lendo a [documentação python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#), porem não ficou claro para mim 
a função de cada um desses metodos no codigo que estou usando, 
gostaria de uma explicação mais clara sobre a função dessas classes
e metodos que estou usando no codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até agora cheguei na seguinte resposta:

Criação de um gerenciador de senhas, faz com que usuario e senha sejam usados como elementos de autenticação:

```
oPass = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
```

Adicionando Elementos de Autenticação ao gerenciador:

```
oPass.add_password(None, Url, User, Password)
```

Criação de um manipulador para senhas (O que eu entendi por handler é que este seria um "tratador" da autenticação.):

```
authHandler = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(oPass)
```

Cria um opener (abridor):

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authHandler)
```

Usa o opener para buscar uma URL // Retorna o XML do serviço requisitado (response)

```
resposta = opener.open("%s%s" %(Url, params))
```

Leitura e exibição do XML:

```
print resposta.read()
```

Fecha a conexão:

```
resposta.close()
```